# Defining executables for a slave on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am very new to CI systems like Jenkins.

I have a master Jenkins server running on Ubuntu. I have one Ubuntu slave (managed over SSH) ,which is dedicated to Android builds, having Android SDK and others already available.

My question is how I can tell the Jenkins master the path of android SDK on the slave server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Manage Jenkins -> Manage Nodes, and open configuration page for the slave node. Add environment variables, which will then be given only to that slave.

If you define environment variables which are used by default by the SDK, then this is enough.  Otherwise you will also have to edit the job to use these (I mean, like in execute shell script build steps).

Comment: Just to emphasize that Slave-related values should be set at the Node-level, as mentioned here, because they are relevant to the slave, and not to the master.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Andriod SDK specifically, but could you pass it as a parameter to the build?